# While and If cycle - Returning both results when conditions a met

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm doing a secant method for root finding problem.

My problem:
I'm using While so the process doesn't go over x iterations, inside the while loop i use a if condition, when it meets the condition it returns the root value (p).
If not it updates and it would return "No root found, exceeded the iterations number."
The thing is, i'm finding a root but i'm also returning the "No root" message.

For instance, i run the script and i get:
No root
No root
No root
root: [Number]

Goal:
To return just one time the root otherwise only one message saying "No root"

Tried to add a new variable "root" inside the if condition so when condition is met that value is now a new variable.

I don't know thought probably it was due to that.

```
**While** i<=iter
p=p1-q1*((p1-p0)/(q1-q0));

**if** abs(p-p1)<tol
root=p;
disp('root:')
disp(root)
return
**endif**

i=i+1;
p0=p1
q0=q1
p1=p
q1=f(p);
disp("no root")
**endwhile**
```

I need to have the one of two, "No root" message or root:[Number]

At the time i'm having both messages.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to take the display outside of the loop, and `break` from the loop rather than `return`.

```
root = nan; % preallocate as if there is no root

while i<=iter
   p=p1-q1*((p1-p0)/(q1-q0));

   if abs(p-p1)<tol
      root=p;
      break
   end

   i=i+1;
   p0=p1
   q0=q1
   p1=p
   q1=f(p);
end

if isnan(root)
   disp("no root")
else
   disp('root:')
   disp(root)
end
```

Comment: thanks a ton really helped!
But if you could spend some more of your time explaining me what's the difference in this case between return and break.

And how can the while cycle knows about variable root? Isn't this one only created when the conditional if happens?

Comment: [return](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/return.html) stops execution of the code (in the current function) at that point and returns control back to the calling function. [break](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/break.html) stops execution of the `while` loop and starts executing the code after the `end` of the `while` loop.  In the former case the `if` statements around the `disp` statements will not execute, and in the latter they will.  `root` is defined before the `while` (just like `tol` and `iter` are, and you seem happy with them working.)